# How do I declare a QGIS custom expression function and use it in a single python script?

Tags: python, qgis-3, qgis-custom-function, pyqgis-3

I would like to create and populate a virtual field in a QGIS vector layer attribute table using a python script.  I think the easiest way to do this is to create a custom expression function, and, then use this function to populate the virtual field.  How do I instantiate a custom expression function from within a python script?  What I have tried with Python 3 from a Python IDE is:

```
    from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom', usesGeometry=False)
def a_function():
    return "'Test'"

QgsExpression.registerFunction(a_function)
print(QgsExpression(a_function()).evaluate())
```

This returns a TypeError:

```
print(QgsExpression(a_function()).evaluate())
TypeError: 'QgsPyExpressionFunction' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 4):

The following works, but, I don't know why:

```
from qgis.core import *
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', usesGeometry=False)
def a_function(feature, parent):
    return 'Test'
print(QgsExpression('a_function()').evaluate())
```

Comment: Custom functions need to always take a `feature` and `parent` argument, which provide access to the feature's attributes, geometry, etc. and the expression which is being evaluated (see https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2017/05/20/how-to-create-custom-functions-in-qgis-using-the-function-editor/ ). Then `QgsExpression` parses and evaluates the expression 'after' it is invoked; it accepts a string to parse and evaluate. Your original invocation without the quotes around `a_function()` tried to evaluate its value rather than parsing it. (The `@qgs` decorator also modifies the definition)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom', usesGeometry=False)
def a_function():

    QgsExpression.registerFunction(a_function)
    print(QgsExpression(a_function()).evaluate())
    return "'Test'"
```

Comment: I would like to call the function in an expression. In my example, the output of print(QgsExpression(a_function()).evaluate()) should be the string 'Test'. . In your provided answer the statement print(QgsExpression(a_function()).evaluate()) does not return anything.