# "'QgsPyExpressionFunction' object is not callable" when using custom function within QgsPyExpressionFunctions in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-custom-function, qgsexpression

I created a function `force_numeric_list` in my QGIS Expression "Function Editor" (see image below) to reuse it in other functions there, e.g. as shown below in the function `get_min_from_attributes()`.

When simply calling the function

```py
force_numeric_list(attrmap_filtered.values(), True)
```

I get the error:

> ```
> 'QgsPyExpressionFunction' object is not callable.
> ```

I've learned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/294739/34517), that this is due to the special circumstance under which the Expression functions are called, needing to have the arguments of feature and parent (however simply passing them with `force_numeric_list(..., feature, parent)` doesn't work either.

I can however evaluate the function like this

```py
QgsExpression('force_numeric_list(attrmap_filtered.values(), True)').evaluate()
```

but this returns `NULL`, which doesn't help (since I need the return value of the function).

How can I call `QgsPyExpressionFunctions` from within `QgsPyExpressionFunctions` and get their return values?

[image: using function force_numeric_list in my QGIS Expression "Function Editor"]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is not about `feature` or `parent` parameter. It arises because the string in `QgsExpression` is not a valid QGIS expression.

`attrmap_filtered.values()` in the expression is a Pythonic syntax, not a valid qgis expression. To pass a Python list to `QgsExpression`, you can convert the list to a string and wrap it in the `array` function.

Let `force_numeric_list` function be:

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def force_numeric_list(values, feature, parent):
    # multiply the values by 10
    values = [v*10 for v in values]    
    return values
```

And `get_min_from_attributes` should be like this:

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def get_min_from_attributes(feature, parent):

    # sample dictionary
    attrmap_filtered = {"a": 1, "b":2}
    
    ##################
    # convert dict values to joint str to use in 'array' function of expression
    values_as_str = ",".join(map(str, attrmap_filtered.values())) # -> '1,2'
    
    # this string has to be a valid expression string
    expr_str = f'force_numeric_list(array({values_as_str}))'
    # the expression is force_numeric_list(array(1,2))'
    ##################
    
    my_vals = QgsExpression(expr_str).evaluate()

    return my_vals
```

Result:

[image]